# Intellisense not working for .cs files in Visual Studio 2015 with Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms, intellisense

All .cs file in my Xamarin project are Miscellaneous files, not referenced to .Droid project i.e.  http://prntscr.com/cp3q4w . I have no Intellisense in .cs files, and it seems like there is somehow missing reference to Xamarin.Forms http://prntscr.com/cp3qzr ,but i dont get compile error for not recognizing xamarin components. This is Xamarin.Forms Shared project.

Tried with this solution: i) Clear the cache ii) Open the solution iii) Unload all projects iv) Load Android project and then fix nuget references v) Once the references were fixed, I loaded the shared project. Now everything seems to work. But, didn't succeed.

Anyone had similar problem? Any suggestions for solution? Thanks.

Comment: A lot of people have problems with Xamarin and Intellisense, myself per example, It's unable to find references. The only final solution usually lies in reinstalling Xamarin from scratch.

Comment: Tried that also, but didn't help. The project setup works fine for 2 other people that work on it, but when I download from repository, the problem exists. .CS files are miscellaneous and no intellisense.

Comment: Can you upload a picture of the structure of your solution? What I don't have clear is the "Miscellaneous files" part, is that the name of a project?

Comment: check if you have previously installed intellisense package from Nuget in VS Extensions and Updates before it was implemented by Xamarin.

Comment: http://prnt.sc/cx4xxh

Comment: Yuri, on this pc, this was the first installation on VS. I downloaded it from xamarin website (Xamarin for VS, around 30~35GB were required for the whole install and all the installation options were set by default ). So there were no  installed intellisense package from Nuget in VS Extensions and Updates before it was implemented by Xamarin

Answer (score 3):

I've often had this problem with Xamarin.  It sometimes happens in my PCL projects, but happens *very* frequently in shared projects.

One of these should fix it:

1) Try going to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# and make sure that "Auto List Members" and "Parameter Information" are checked.  This fixes things almost all the time in PCL projects, and it ***sometimes*** fixes it in shared projects.

2) Try the following:

1. Close **ALL OPEN INSTANCES** of VS2015.
2. In windows explorer, go to the directory with the solution that's giving you problems.
3. Find the .vs subdirectory there and delete it.  ***Note***: it may be hidden, so you need to show hidden files.
4. Restart VS2015 and open the solution.  IntelliSense should be working again.

**A few notes on option #2:**

- It's important to note that doing this will also delete other user-specific solution settings, so you may have to reset your startup project.
- If you're concerned with deleting the directory, you can try renaming it instead.
- You have to make sure all VS2015 instances are closed for this to work.  Not sure why, however.
- This isn't a permanent fix.  For whatever reason, IntelliSense will eventually stop working again and you'll have to repeat the procedure.  It's very frustrating, and I wish that either the Xamarin or VS team would fix it.

Comment: Rand, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately both suggestions didn't worked for me.

Comment: Deleting the .vs directory fixes this for me. It's temporary however, it reoccurs after awhile  :)

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin does not support long paths, so if the names of the projects or the files are long Intellisense will not work.

`The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters`

You can run Visual Studio with traces enabled to verify if you are having these problem.

1. Close Visual Studio.
2. Open a Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt.
3. Set environment variable `TraceDesignTime` to true (`set TraceDesignTime=true`).
4. Delete .vs directory/.suo file.
5. Restart VS from the command prompt you set the environment variable (`devenv`).
6. Open the solution.
7. Check `C:\Users\[user_name]\AppData\Local\Temp\project_name_*.designtime.log` and look for the failed tasks (FAILED).

Typical situation: the names of some generated files inside `obj` directory are too long.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me. From the solution explorer window, right click on the shared project and Unload it. Close visual studio and run it again. Now you can reload the shared project from solution explorer and this time, The intellisense gets back.